# Polymorphic relation in production and test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model Message with source attribute, and two inherited models which can be source:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :source, :polymorphic => true
end

class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class A < Parent
  has_many :messages, :as => :source
end

class B < Parent
  has_many :messages, :as => :source
end
```

The problem is in test environment the `message.source_type` attribute is A or B, depends on the source's type. But when I try to use the app in production the `message.source_type` is `Parent`.

```
message = Message.new
a = A.new
message.source = a
# test mode: message.source_type == A
# production mode: message.source_type == Parent
```

I tried to fix the `source_type` with `message.source_type = A.to_s`, but it didn't help. Do you know good solution to work my software in production in the same way like in test env?

Answer (score 2):

you shouldnt call your classes Base, it will make you big problems because Base is reserved for some ruby/rails classes.. maybe this is the problme..

Comment: It was just an example. My class name is different. Sorry for the bad name! (Should I edit it?)